# Calling same Jquery file many times

Tags: jquery

I have multiple instances where I use jquery on my site (like an image slider and navigation) but they will not work if I do not place the jquery call multiple times.

E.g. the 2 snippets below won't work unless I call the script twice. Please help. (There are more jquery calls on my page as well calling different libraries) Can't I just call the latest library once and be done with it? I tried and doesn't work.

```
<!--menu -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/newnav.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/navdoublecolumn.js"></script>
<script>
<!--
ddmegamenu.docinit({
    menuid:'solidmenu',
    dur:0, 
    easing:'easeInOutCirc' //<--no comma after last setting
})
// -->
</script>



<!-- slide -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.tabSlideOut.v1.3.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('.slideout1').tabSlideOut({
        tabHandle: '.slideouthandle1',             //class of the element that will become your tab
        pathToTabImage: 'images/slideouttab_chat.jpg',//path to the image for the tab //Optionally can be set using css
        imageHeight: '150px',                     //height of tab image           //Optionally can be set using css
        imageWidth: '40px',                       //width of tab image            //Optionally can be set using css
        tabLocation: 'left',                      //side of screen where tab lives, top, right, bottom, or left
        speed: 200,                               //speed of animation
        action: 'click',                          //options: 'click' or 'hover', action to trigger animation
        topPos: '215px',                          //position from the top/ use if tabLocation is left or right
        leftPos: '20px',                          //position from left/ use if tabLocation is bottom or top
        fixedPosition: true                       //options: true makes it stick(fixed position) on scroll
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: To clarify, why does <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script> need to be called each time? I sure it doesn't. Can someone please help me out with this?

Comment: it should not be called each time, once per html page... the only cause may be if you redefine `$` or used `jQuery.noconflict()`

Comment: Don't know if this matters but I'm using a CMS that injects head section on the fly

Comment: Also where I place the call, makes things work of not

Comment: So if I'm redefining $ for each snippet, does that mean I have to call it multiple times? Please help

Comment: I am using jQuery.noconflict(). Does that mean I have to call it several times?

Comment: that means you should call jQuery functions as `jQuery()` instead of `$()`

Answer (score 1):

I expect something in `navdoublecolumn.js` is overwriting or otherwise breaking jQuery functionality.  By including jQuery a second time, you are redefining the methods / variables and therefore restoring functionality that `navdoublecolumn.js` has broken.

You may get a clue to what is breaking by looking at the javascript console error output you get when you remove the second jQuery inclusion.

Comment: So are you saying that in that case I have no choice but to call it again?

Comment: No. I'm saying that if you don't call it again you have a chance of working out what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

As you using `jQuery.noconflict()` use this:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('.slideout1').tabSlideOut({
        tabHandle: '.slideouthandle1',             //class of the element that will become your tab
        pathToTabImage: 'images/slideouttab_chat.jpg',//path to the image for the tab //Optionally can be set using css
        imageHeight: '150px',                     //height of tab image           //Optionally can be set using css
        imageWidth: '40px',                       //width of tab image            //Optionally can be set using css
        tabLocation: 'left',                      //side of screen where tab lives, top, right, bottom, or left
        speed: 200,                               //speed of animation
        action: 'click',                          //options: 'click' or 'hover', action to trigger animation
        topPos: '215px',                          //position from the top/ use if tabLocation is left or right
        leftPos: '20px',                          //position from left/ use if tabLocation is bottom or top
        fixedPosition: true                       //options: true makes it stick(fixed position) on scroll
    });

});
```

Comment: instead of immediatly downvoting you can tell what error is, you using noconflict, show how.